# How to compare session value with a multpile folder name in php?

Tags: php

If there is a multiple folder from which you want to retrieve a data or read a file. For example there are 10 folder named :

- A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J

And you are sending a value in session, how to write condition to which folder to be read instead of writing a long code of **if else** like this

```
        if($_SESSION["val"]== 'A')
         {
          //code to read the folder
         } elseif ($_SESSION["val"]== 'B')
         {
          // code to read the folder
         } elseif ($_SESSION["val"]== 'c')
         {
          // code to read the folder
         } elseif ($_SESSION["val"]== 'D')
         {
         // code to read the folder
         }
```

Is there any possible way to make this code shorter? Since writing if else for each values will be tedious.

Comment: You could use an array and a loop. The array would store the possible values and which folder each goes to. Your loop then would iterate over the array to see if session val equals one in the array, and handle it accordingly.

Comment: you can create array of folders like `$arr =  [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]` and then simply check `if(in_array($_SESSION["val"], $arr)) { `

Comment: Thanks i haven't even thought, since m a beginner..this helped me @VibhaChosla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's unclear what you're trying to achieve, but this might help shorten your code:

```
$folders = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
if( in_array($_SESSION['val'], $folders) ) {
  $the_folder = $_SESSION['val'];
  // do whatever you wanna do here
}
```

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do the **same logic** for all `IF` statements,

```php
$folders = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
if( in_array($_SESSION['val'], $folders) ) {
  // your logic
}
```

If you are going to do **different logic** for **each** `IF` statements,

```php
switch ($_SESSION['val']) {
    case 'A':
        // logic for A
        break;
    case 'B':
        // logic for B
        break;
    case 'C':
        // logic for C
        break;
    case 'D':
        // logic for D
        break;
    case 'E':
        // logic for E
        break;
}
```